# list of all sqlConnection created by my .net application

Tags: .net, sql-server, performance, wcf

I am working on net project (WCF service). Code is not so good at many places in code sql connection is not properly handled. I am using SOAP UI for tesing web API. I have created SOAP UI project. Now I would like to know list of all sql connection created by my SOAP UI test when i ran SOAP UI test project. 
Is there any way to get list of all connection?. Please let me know. [I just wanted to show this result to management to get code refactor approval.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I wrote a post how to collect ADO.NET traces. As far as I know these traces are the most detailed logs of ADO.NET activity in your application - just tune them to your needs. The post is available here: https://lowleveldesign.wordpress.com/2012/09/07/diagnosing-ado-net-with-etw-traces/. If you have any problems just let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sebastian Solnica!! really very good article feeling great !!

Answer (score 1):

You can run this query to find the list of active sessions for each database and then get the one that you want accordingly.

```
select 
    db_name(dbid) as [Database Name], 
    count(dbid) as [No Of Connections],
    loginame as [Login Name]
from
    sys.sysprocesses
where 
    dbid > 0
group by 
    dbid, loginame
```

Its taken from the following link.
[Find active sessions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/389725/How-to-find-the-active-SQL-connections-and-kill-th)